# Setting PRE tab width in different web browsers

Tags: css, tabs, width, pre

There's a way to set PRE tab width in Firefox and Opera, but there isn't a well-known way to do this in IE or Chrome, and hard-tabbed code in PRE tags suffers as a result.

```
pre {
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;
    white-space: -pre-wrap;
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -moz-tab-size: 1.5em;
    -o-tab-size: 1.5em;

    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    width: 65%;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't this and block vertical centering trivial in CSS3? Basic layouts are far more useful than rounded corners.

Answer (score 7):

According to MDN's [tab-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/tab-size) page, the proper format is :

```
tab-size: 4;
-moz-tab-size: 4;
-o-tab-size: 4;
```

JavaScript fallback :

```
var fix_tab_size = function(pre, size) {
    if(typeof fix_tab_size.supports === 'undefined') {
        var bs = document.body.style;
        fix_tab_size.supports = ('tab-size' in bs || '-o-tab-size' in bs || '-ms-tab-size' in bs || '-moz-tab-size'  in bs);
    }
    if(!fix_tab_size.supports) {
        if(typeof pre.each === 'function') { //jquery 
            $('pre').each(function() {
                var t = $(this);
                t.html(t.html().replace(/\t/g, new Array(size+1).join(' ')));
            });
        } else if(typeof pre.innerHTML === 'string') {
            pre.innerHTML = pre.innerHTML.replace(/\t/g, new Array(size+1).join(' '));
        }
    }
}
$(function() {
    fix_tab_size($('pre'),4);
    //or
    $.getJSON(src, function(data) {
        fix_tab_size($data_pre.html(data.code)); //etc
    });
});
```

Comment: Bummer that Opera will never see a standard tab-width style. rip.

Comment: I don't use Opera, however the newest Opera uses Blink, Google's webkit fork, so it might support it.

Comment: Of to clarify, I mean Pesto based opera, 12.x has been discontinued supporting only the -o-tab-width declaration. essentially meaning that us Opera users (predominately on linux) will almost never see tab-size styles properly, unless developers copy this example and decide to include the opera-specific spec.

Comment: Your JavaScript checks if `-ms-tab-size` is supported, but your CSS doesn't try to set it. Presumably one these should be changed.

Answer (score -2):

The CSS 3 Text feature `tab-size` is too new (and not nearly standardised enough) to have seen wide deployment so far (plus tabs aren't very popular in general).

For the case of hard-tabbed code, just run it through a tabs-to-spaces conversion before putting it on the page.

> Basic layouts are far more useful than rounded corners

Tabs were never intended to do general-purpose layout tasks (and would be completely unsuitable for that). There are more powerful layout features being touted for CSS3—see for example Grid and Flexbox in IE10.

Comment: -1: There are equally many (if not more) arguments against "hard-spaced" code.

Comment: -1 because using tabs for coding and setting the tab-size in your favorite editor is more visually appealing and convenient than using spaces.